# Angular Component Attribute Type Conversion Issues

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component I am attempting to have edit an existing database listing of this fictional buy/sell app I'm working on.  The specific error I am receiving, on startup, is the following:

```
Error: src/app/edit-listing-page/edit-listing-page.component.html:8:9 - error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    [currentPrice] = "listing.price">

src/app/edit-listing-page/edit-listing-page.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './edit-listing-page.component.html',
                    
    Error occurs in the template of component EditListingPageComponent.
```

What am I missing? Thanks, Ironman

**edit-listing-page.component.html**

```
<div class="content-box" *ngIf="listing">
    <h2>Edit Listing</h2>
    <app-listing-data-form 
        buttonText="Save Changes"
        (onSubmit)="onSubmit($event)"
        [currentName]="listing.name"
        [currentDescription]="listing.description"
        [currentPrice]= "listing.price" >
    </app-listing-data-form>
</div>
<div class="content-box" *ngIf="!listing">
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
</div>
```

**edit-listing-page.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ListingsService } from '../listings.service';
import { Listing } from '../types';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-listing-page',
  templateUrl: './edit-listing-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-listing-page.component.css']
})
export class EditListingPageComponent implements OnInit {
  listing: Listing;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private listingsService: ListingsService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.listingsService.getListingById(id) 
      .subscribe(listing => this.listing = listing);
  }

  onSubmit({name, description, price}):void{
    alert('Saving changes to the listing...');
    this.listingsService.editListing(this.listing.id, name, description, price)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/my-listings');
      });
    
  }
}
```

**types.ts**

```
export interface Listing{
    id: string,
    name: string,
    description: string,
    price:number,
    views: number,
};
```

**listings.service.ts**

```
 editListing(id:string, name:string, description:string, price:number): Observable<Listing>{
    return this.http.post<Listing>(
      `/api/listings/${id}`,
      {name, description, price }, 
      httpOptions,
    );
  }
```

**listing-data-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Listing } from '../types';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listing-data-form',
  templateUrl: './listing-data-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listing-data-form.component.css']
})
export class ListingDataFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() buttonText;
  @Input() currentName = '';
  @Input() currentDescription= '';
  @Input() currentPrice= '';
  name:string = '';
  description:string = '';
  price:string = '';

  @Output() onSubmit = new EventEmitter<Listing>();

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.name = this.currentName;
    this.description = this.currentDescription;
    this.price = this.currentPrice;
  }

  onButtonClicked(): void{
    this.onSubmit.emit({
      id: null,
      name: this.name,
      description: this.description,
      price:Number(this.price),
      views: 0,
    });
  }

}
```

**listing-data-form.component.html**

```
<div>
        <label for="price">
            Price:
        </label>
        <input id="price" name="price" type="text" [(ngModel)] = "price" />
    </div>
        <button type="submit">{{buttonText}}</button>
```

Comment: @depperm, aren't I doing that here?  price:Number(this.price),

Comment: Before that, after you take inputs, price is being typed as string. That would be the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your listing-data-form.component.ts

```
  @Input() currentPrice= '';
  ...
  price:string = '';
```

Should be

```
  @Input() currentPrice= 0;
  ...
  price:number = 0;
```